# Undo git rm . -r --cached or commit changes?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-rm

I was trying to make my .gitingore work ([Link to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11451535/gitignore-not-working) :) ).

I have just done

```
git rm . -r --cached
```

and now I have a whole list of deleted files when I enter:

```
git status -s
```

Is this normal? 
Can i safetly commit all my changes?

Or maybe there is a way to undo this command?

PS: I was trying to understand what this command do but i've only found this: http://brianloomis.wordpress.com/2009/08/10/git-rm-r-cached/
And it's not so clear to me.

PS 2: OK :) To save my skin I've made a reset:

```
git reset HEAD *
```

The DELETED files went bye bye :) There are no longer visible in git status -s .
But still is it safe to do the command:

```
git rm . -r --cached and then add and commit it?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"safe"? What it does is empty the index and commit the deletion of those files, *without* removing them from the working tree (your disk)

That means all those files become un-tracked (private).

Usually, you don't commit after such a command. You reset (as you did).
That can force content drivers (like a [smudge script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14282199/6309)) or other `.gitattributes` directives to be applied again on all files.

You can see that command used in the GitHub help page "[Dealing with line endings](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings)".

```
git rm --cached -r .
# Remove everything from the index.

git reset --hard
# Write both the index and working directory from git's database.
```

Again, in this case: no commit, only a reset.

Comment: Would it be correct to change "commit the deletion" to "stage the deletion"?

Comment: @unutbu "stage" means recording in the index (stage). That is what git rm --cached does already. If you commit after that, you create a new commit which records the deletion of those files in the git repo.

Comment: So if i would do add and commit after rm --cached command i would simply remove all files from repository?? :O (Not sure if i got this right) :)

Comment: @Mr.TK no: if you would commit *directly after* the git rm --cached, you would record the deletion, meaning anyone else cloning the latest commit wouldn't see those file. Since you did a `git rm --cached -r`, those files are still on your disk (working tree), but untrack. If you did a `git add` right after the `git rm`... that wouldn't do much, but restore the index you just emptied.

Comment: Oh... so that was a safe thing to do.  :)
I wanted to clear indexes on those files.
Also I still wanted them in repo.

Comment: @Mr.TK Yes. I prefer a `git reset` (with or without the `--hard`) to restore in the index. `git add` can add "too much".

Comment: Thank You for your help. Have a wonderful night/day - what ever you having now (i assume beer is an option too )   ;)

Comment: @Mr.TK you are welcome. Almost 8AM here. The day is just starting.

Comment: So... We are in the same timezone. :) 11:20 AM :)