# Doxygen for local repo

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial

Currently I have a code repository which is not well documented, called ''`A`'', in a remote server.
I have a local clone of it, called ''`B`''.

I want to accompany the following two things:

1. add Doxygen-style comments to ''`B`'' to generate documents.
2. push changesets to ''`A`'' without these comments in ''`B`''.

What is the best way to set up repo/branches to achieve this?

Comment: I see that the git and svn tags were added in an edit. If you specifically are asking for how to achieve this in mercurial, I suggest you specify that in your question and remove the svn and git tags

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a second branch in `B` which:

- can be used to merge the main branch of `B` where those Doxygen-style comment are added (so: merge from main branch to second branch)
- but has a config activating a [smudge content filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36669007/6309), with `smudge` being a script removing all Doxygen comments (that is, if those comments are easy to parse and detect)

[image: smudge]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>

That involves a `.gitattributes` files (present only in the second branch)

```
*.cpp filter=removeDoxygen
```

(replace `cpp` by the right extension for your project sources)

And that involves a local config:

```
 git config filter.removeDoxygen.smudge 'removeDoxygen'
```

With `removeDoxygen` being a shell script anywhere in your `$PATH`.
(it can be a shell script even on Windows, as it will be executed by the msysgit shell)

That merge will result in files automatically modified (by the `smudge` script), and they will need to be added and committed in that second branch.

Then push said second branch to repo `A`.

Comment: More specific to my user case: ''A'' is maintained by mercurial and some code in ''A'' already has doxygen style comment. What is the best action here?

Comment: @user103500 I assume  is managed by git. Nothing change for repo B: the comments will be removed in second branch. When pushing back to A (http://hg-git.github.io/), those comments should remain gone.

Comment: @user103500 if B is not directly cloned from A, I would suggest to push to a new branch in A, and then make a mercurial merge within the mercurial repo A.

Comment: I do not want to remove original comments in ''A'' when I push upstream. I do want to remove my comments in ''B'' when I push upstream. ''B'' is directly cloned from ''A'' in my case.

Comment: @user103500 is B a git repo?

Comment: @user103500 if not, you need the equivalent of smudge for mercurial (for your repo B): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271504/mercurial-equivalent-of-gitattributes-smudge-clean-filters